# JQueryUI Dialog TinyMCE Issues

Tags: tinymce, jquery-ui-dialog

i am having some problems with the TinyMCE (V3.4.7) and JqueryUI (V1.8.14) Dialog

the following Fiddler link shows my example purfectly [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hZM59/1/)

What i am trying to do is open a JqueryUI Dialog box with a TinyMCE WYSIWYG Editor in it.

the first time it displays properly. but if you click close and then reopen the box it will not show the Editor but just the TextArea.

Any help would be good. Thanks

***Update***

I did find out a solution that works for me, i have put up the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qpirate/kRmnb/4/)
What i am doing is check to see if the dialog has been opened before  and if so just open it, then in the Open Function i test to see if the box contains an element with *id*_parent
if it does then this will be the editor (so do nothing) otherwise just init as usual.

it seems there is a problem with the JQuery Plug in as it does not remove the elements when you call tinyMCE.execCommand('mceRemoveControl',false,'editor_id') and when you re-add the editor it attaches to the first box available.

Comment: realy useful question and even better solutiin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that you need to shut down tinymce correctly in order to open an editor with the same id.

Use:

```
ed.execCommand('mceRemoveControl', false, 'editor_id');// editor_id equals the id of your textarea
```

Comment: I am removing the Control if you look in the function removeTinyMCE which is called both on the Close Button and the Close Dialog event handlers.

Comment: you are right. have a look at this modified fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/EVuaC/ . maybe this helps.